# Why very simple javascript code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

the script:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6;
```

It is supposed to show the result but nothing happens. I added a separate `myScript.js` file to write the code. In HTML I wrote:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
```

What has to be the problem ?

Comment: do you have something like this `<div id="demo"></div>` as well? do you perform the assignment later than the html part?

Comment: Is the JavaScript executed *after* the element in question? Otherwise, you should get an exception on the console, when trying to access it.

Comment: where did you put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>` ?

Comment: It's working now . Still don't know what I did . Thanks for the aswers !

Answer (score 0):

You need an element with id `demo` for this to work

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

The problem in your case is probably the positioning of the included script tag. It is executed, as soon as it is parsed by the browser, but the `demo` tag is not loaded at this point.

Try

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 5 + 6;
}
```

This will execute your code only after the document has loaded and the `demo` element is available.

Comment: This was just a matter of format, the OP has added an element with this ID

Comment: I see. I will still leave the answer, because it shows that the exact code of the OP is working

Comment: _"Works for me"_ answers that have the same code as the question are not particularly helpful. The difference here that won't be obvious to OP is that the script part in Stack Snippets runs after the HTML is loaded

Comment: At the time I wrote it, it was not a "works-for-me" answer.

Comment: I refer to your comment ~ _"I will still leave the answer, because it shows that the exact code of the OP is working"_. Anyway, nice edit +1

Comment: You are right. It was the heat of the moment ;)